# Abnormally long computation time using AppellF1 function

Tags: special-functions, timing

I am trying to use the `AppellF1` function in Mathematica 13.3.1 on an Ubuntu machine with an i7 13700. The inbuilt function seems to be much slower in some cases than numerically computing the function using the integral form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Integral_representations)

For example, I have a function which is a definite integral

```
J2[n_, A_, B_]:= NIntegrate[((B - y^2)/(A - y^2))^((n + 1)/2) 1/Sqrt[1 - y^2], {y, 0, 1}]
```

where `A>B>1`. It can be analytically shown that this function is equivalent to

```
J2Appell[n_,A_,B_]:=(1/2)*(B/A)^((n + 1)/2)*Beta[1/2, 1/2]AppellF1[1/2, -(n + 1)/2, (n + 1)/2, 1, 1/B, 1/A]
```

For trial values, say n = 11, A = 1.6, B = 1.1, `AbsoluteTiming[]` returns the following:

```
AbsoluteTiming[J2[11, 1.6, 1.1]]

{0.005844, 0.0628803}
```

```
AbsoluteTiming[J2Appell[11, 1.6, 1.1]]

{19.9175, 0.0628803}
```

Oddly, subsequent runs of `J2Appell[]` for the same `n` and different values of `A` and `B` take comparatively less time to run.

```
AbsoluteTiming[J2Appell[11, 1.2, 1.1]]
AbsoluteTiming[J2Appell[11, 1.6, 1.4]]

{0.664203, 0.54187}
{0.50949, 0.445163}
```

This seems to be a major issue only for odd values of `n`, where even values seem to run in about `0.03s`. This is still an order of magnitude slower than using `NIntegrate[]`.

I would greatly appreciate any help regarding this issue. If I need to provide any additional information I would be happy to do so.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a known bug involving slow computations with `AppellF1`. I will add a link to the thread in the bug report so the relevant developers will be aware it has appeared again.